# Particular Solution Setup (Method Of Undetermined Coefficients)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

"Find a particular solution for $y'' + 2y' - 3y = 1 + xe^x$"

**My Work So Far**

I'm getting the wrong solution for this (keep ending up with 2 equations to solve 3 variables), and the process is quite long, so I'd just like to get some verification for whether my setup is correct. If it isn't, then that's the problem solved. If it *is,* then I'm probably adding a term wrong somewhere, not surprising with how tedious particular solutions are. I'm using the Method Of Undetermined Coefficients:

$y_{complementary} = C_1e^x+C_2xe^x$ (simply found with $r^2 + 2r - 3 = 0$)

For $f(x) = 1 + xe^x,$ I need to break it into two parts: $1$, and $xe^x$

$1:$ This is a polynomial with zeroes for the $x$ terms, so its contribution will be $A$.

$xe^x:$ This fits into the form $($polynomial  of  $x$$)e^{rx}$, so its contribution to the solution will be $x^s(Bx+C)e^x$, where $s$ is the smallest non-negative integer that avoids any terms being duplicates of $y_{complementary}.$ In this case, $s = 1$, and therefore:

---

$y_{particular} = A + (Bx^2 + Cx)e^x $.

---

Now, is this setup correct?

Comment: I think you should check the roots of your characteristic polynomial again.

Comment: Oh geez, so much looking over the calculus that I missed a basic factoring error. Thank you, what a stupid mistake.

Comment: Even if your reasoning was slightly faulty, the parametrization of the particular solution is correct. Please add additional steps if the original problem (2 equations for 3 variables) persists.